# Return the native text WITHOUT parsing from PHP script to ajax script

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, innerhtml, getelementbyid

Hi I am not sure how to return intact data to object xmlhttprequest's responsetext by means of innerhtml, that is without parsing. In the listing 1, it works. But when I used listing 2 as shown below, to send text from php, it does not work. And Listing3 shows php script. The output is that I see return is text, instead of being processing by dygraph function
Thanks in advance.

```
Listing1:-
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
     {
          if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
      {
             z = new Dygraph(document.getElementById("showrealchart"),
                  "Batch,S1,S2,S3,S4,S5,S6,S7,S8,S9,S10,\n" +
"1, 3.65, 5.00, 4.53, 5.01, 10.50, 0.03, 9.05, 5.05, 5.22, 6.23\n"+
"7, 3.65, 5.03, 4.50, 5.02, 9.50, 0.05, 9.15, 5.55, 5.20, 6.23\n"+
"8, 3.67, 5.00, 4.53, 4.99, 9.00, 0.04, 9.30, 5.10, 2.30, 6.22\n"+
"12, 3.65, 5.04, 4.53, 4.99, 10.05, 0.35, 9.00, 5.23, 5.20, 6.21\n"+
"16, 3.66, 5.00, 4.50, 4.98, 10.50, 1.01, 9.01, 5.20, 5.10, 6.24\n"+
"18, 3.65, 5.02, 4.70, 5.00, 9.80, 0.45, 9.14, 5.63, 5.15, 6.23\n");
      }
     }
```

Now I would like return the data in exact form.

```
Listing 2:-
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
        {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
            {
                z = new Dygraph
                document.getElementById("showrealchart").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
```

And Php script.

```
Listing 3;-
<?php
print '"Batch,S1,S2,S3,S4,S5,S6,S7,S8,S9,S10,\n" +
"1, 3.65, 5.00, 4.53, 5.01, 10.50, 0.03, 9.05, 5.05, 5.22, 6.23\n"+
"7, 3.65, 5.03, 4.50, 5.02, 9.50, 0.05, 9.15, 5.55, 5.20, 6.23\n"+
"8, 3.67, 5.00, 4.53, 4.99, 9.00, 0.04, 9.30, 5.10, 2.30, 6.22\n"+
"12, 3.65, 5.04, 4.53, 4.99, 10.05, 0.35, 9.00, 5.23, 5.20, 6.21\n"+
"16, 3.66, 5.00, 4.50, 4.98, 10.50, 1.01, 9.01, 5.20, 5.10, 6.24\n"+
"18, 3.65, 5.02, 4.70, 5.00, 9.80, 0.45, 9.14, 5.63, 5.15, 6.23\n";';
?>
```

Comment: you might want to use <br> instead of \n since html doesn't threat new line as a display modifier when it renders.

Comment: user1739825 Maybe I misunderstood you question. Did you try put `header('Content-type: text/plain')` before printing the result

Comment: In javascript,`"\n"` actually means a line-feed, so your `z` in listing 1 should getting a multiline string; But in your PHP in listing 3, you are sending _literal_ `\n` and double quotes. I think this may be something you want to inspect.

Comment: Hi All Just found out that there's an article for this question  regarding native data sent at the xmlhttprequest. It maybe be useful to you though the solution does not work. <http://dygraphs.com/data.html> @Rezigned

Answer (score 0):

You are returning a string literal. This won't work, as you will actually get:

```
document.getElementById("showrealchart").innerHTML="\"Batch, ....\"";
```

Note the quotes are doubled.

If you remove quotes from PHP, like this:

```
print 'Batch,S1,S2...\n1 3.65...\n';
```

your javascript callback will get this as a string to use.

Or if you want a long version in PHP, you can do one of the following:

```
$res = print 'Batch,S1,S2...\n' .
       '1, 3.65, ...\n' .
       ....;
print $res;
```

But also depending on what your client Js does with the data, you might want to play with the \n bits, send all this as a JSON or do whatever else.

Answer (score 0):

I not quite sure why you execute the the code in Listing 1 and 2 differently. But I believe this is what you want.

Listing 2.

```
var z = new Dygraph(document.getElementById("showrealchart"), xmlhttp.responseText);
```

Listing 3.

```
<?php
# ... is the rest of your data
echo <<<TXT
Batch,S1,S2,S3,S4,S5,S6,S7,S8,S9,S10
1, 3.65, 5.00, 4.53, 5.01, 10.50, 0.03, 9.05, 5.05, 5.22, 6.23
7, 3.65, 5.03, 4.50, 5.02, 9.50, 0.05, 9.15, 5.55, 5.20, 6.23
...
...
TXT;
?>
```